# How to remove functions from fishshell without deleting the function file directly?

Tags: function, fish

I've defined a function `hello` in fishshell:

```bash
function hello
    echo Hello
end
```

And save it:

```bash
funcsave hello
```

If I want to delete it, I can delete the file `~/.config/fish/functions/hello.fish`.

Is there any other way to do it? (like built-in `funcdel` or `funcrm`)

Answer (score 28):

No, there isn't any builtin to remove the file, but you can use:

```bash
    functions --erase hello
```

or

```bash
    functions -e hello
```

to erase the function definition from the current session.

#### See also

- [Documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#functions)

Answer (score 15):

I created another fish function for that

```bash
function funcdel
    if test -e ~/.config/fish/functions/$argv[1].fish
        rm ~/.config/fish/functions/$argv[1].fish
        echo 'Deleted function ' $argv[1]
    else
        echo 'Not found function ' $argv[1]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

The above solution of `functions -e hello` only deletes `hello` in the **current session**. Open another terminal, and the function is still there.

To delete the function in a **persistent** way, I had to resort to deleting the file `~/.config/fish/functions/hello.fish` directly. Up till now, I do not know of another way that does deleting in a persistent way.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure why this is not mentioned anywhere else?

Answer (score 6):

a more complete, self defined (and quiet) self-crafted solution, inspired by @Kanzee's answer (copy to file `~/.config/fish/functions/funcdel.fish`):

```
function funcdel --description 'Deletes a fish function both permanently and from memory'
    set -l fun_name $argv[1]
    set -l fun_file ~/.config/fish/functions/$fun_name.fish

    # Delete the in-memory function, if it exists
    functions --erase $fun_name

    # Delete the function permanently,
    # if it exists as a file in the regular location
    if test -e $fun_file
        rm $fun_file
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when this was added to fish, but `funcsave` deletes the function file if the corresponding function has been deleted in the current session (using `functions --erase`).

> If you have erased a function using functions’s `--erase` option, `funcsave` will remove the saved function definition.
>
> – [`funcsave` documentation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/funcsave.html)

Example session where I define, save, erase and finally save again to remove the file:

```
$ function hello_world
      echo "Hello world!"
  end
$ hello_world
Hello world!
$ funcsave hello_world
funcsave: wrote /home/user/.config/fish/functions/hello_world.fish
$ functions --erase hello_world
$ funcsave hello_world
funcsave: removed /home/user/.config/fish/functions/hello_world.fish
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answer from @hoijui with some code from the function funcsave, so you can delete more than one function at once:

```bash
    function funcdel --description 'Deletes a fish function both permanently and from memory'
        set cf (status function)
        set -l options 'h/help'
        argparse -n funcdel $options -- $argv
        or return

        # should create a manpage
        if set -q _flag_help
            __fish_print_help cf
            return 0
        end

        if not set -q argv[1]
            printf (_ "%ls: Expected at least %d args, got only %d\n") $cf 1 0
            return 1
        end
    
        set -l retval 0
        for funcname in $argv
            set -l funcfile $__fish_config_dir/functions/$funcname.fish

            # Delete the in-memory function, if it exists
            functions --query -- $funcname
            if test $status -eq 0
                functions --erase -- $funcname
                printf (_ "%s: function %s removed from session\n") $cf $funcname
            else
                printf (_ "%s: Unknown function '%s'\n") $cf $funcname
            end

            # Delete the function permanently,
            # if it exists as a file in the regular location
            if test -e $funcfile
                rm $funcfile
                printf (_ "%s: %s deleted\n") $cf $funcfile
            else
                printf (_ "%s: %s not found\n") $cf $funcfile
            end
        end

        return $retval
    end
```